# Dell monitor does not run on native resolution of 1600x900 pixel when connected to early macbook pro retina 2015 via thunderbolt

Tags: thunderbolt, resolution, displayport, vga-adapter, vga

just a few hours ago I got 2 dell [E2015HV](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00M1C47EU) monitors, they are VGA monitors with a native resolution of 1600x900 pixel and since the macbook pro retina does not have any VGA ports I'm using two [VGA to thunderbolt converters](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B015ZNSMB0) to connect the two displays to the computer to make them an extended display, but for some reason none of the displays want to run on their native resolution, and when I `option` + click on the scaled display setting from display preferences I see a list of custom resolutions but not one of them are the monitor's native resolution of 1600x900 pixel, as a matter of fact none of the resolutions listed in the list box even begin with the number 1600. So, the question now is that is there anything I can do to make them run on their native resolution? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your monitors, neither your Mac. That's a compatibility issue with your adapter. There are many comments on Amazon complaining about the same issue on similar converters. That seems, unfortunately, a hardware fault.

Example: [http://www.amazon.com/gp/aw/cr/B00NH13I08/ref=mw_dp_cr](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00NH13I08)

Comment: hi, thank you for replying back, i already ordered another adapter from apple and i'll let you on the results when it comes. thanks for replying though :)

Comment: well.... buying a thunderbolt to VGA converter from apple did the trick, all my external monitors are now running at their full native resolution.

Comment: Great to hear that. I have had similar issues with 3rd party converters as well. Apple manages to turn everything, including cables, proprietary...